# Multiple show/hide div with different function

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to do a div with next and prev using `hide and show` on JQUERY with different function each. And I want also the last is `Finish` not back to first div

this is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/854/

I want on page1 when pressed the next I load the ajax, but don't know where to use that function, then on page2, different function, but on my jsfiddle it's same all

**EDIT1**

*added code, asked by Praveen*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

// I WANT TO CALL THESE
function page1()
{
    alert('page1');
  //call my function on page1
}

function page2()
{
    alert('new function');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="divs">
    <div class="cls1">1</div>
    <div class="cls2">2</div>
    <div class="cls3">3</div>
    <div class="cls4">4</div>
</div>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>
```

Comment: Add code in the post. Don't bypass validation.

Comment: yeah, posted the code, it's on the JSFIDDLE already

Comment: **Add code in the post.**

Comment: @PraveenKumar here it is

Answer (score 0):

You can save your functions in array like this:

```
var funs = [
  function() {
     console.log('1 function');
  },
  function() {
     console.log('2 function');
  }
];
```

and call this function in your click handler like this:

```
var i = $(".divs div:visible").index();
funs[i] && funs[i]();
```

or

```
if (typeof funs[i] == 'function') {
    funs[i]();
}
```

or without the array like :

```
if (i == 0) {
    page1();
} else if (i == 1) {
   page2();
}
```

Comment: can you explain me what is this? sorry I'm just newbie `funs[i] && funs[i]();`

Comment: @StormSpirit it check if `funs[i]` have value (the function) and then if so execute the function from funs array. I've added different snippet.